# Bad runtime when using previously defined variables in KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I get very bad runtime when running the following query in KQL:

```
range x from my_Auslegungstemp to 15 step 0.05
| extend y = my_a*x+my_b+max_diff_prog_real+0.05*(my_b+max_diff_prog_real)
| extend flag = "Regression_neu"
```

All of these variables are previously defined in "let"-Statements

The query needs around 1 minute to run which seems like a lot.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the full query (you can put it here, if you're ok with that).
But most chances are that the calculation of the variables (my_a, my_b and max_diff_prog_real) is what takes most of the time.

I suggest you go over the way you calculate the variables, and see if they are calculated efficiently. If they are all based on some other `let` statement, then make sure to use the `materialize()` function (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction).

Also, take a look at the [Query Best Practices doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices), where you might find some other useful tips.
The most frequent mistakes are:

- Use of `contains` instead of `has` (`has` is much more performant, but has slightly different semantics)
- Use of `join` where the left side is significantly larger than the right one (for best performance, the left side should be the small one)
- Use of `order by` early in the query (which significantly decreases the parallelism of the query), instead of using the [`array_sort_asc()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraysortascfunction)
- Not putting filters on a DateTime column

Comment: Thanks a lot, the materialize() function helped the most!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)